# Tile on Start menu does not update with new App Version

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I uploaded a new version of my app with some new icon.
But if I already have the old tile on start menu, I have to delete it to pin the new one.

Is there any config to force app to do it by itself or do I have to code that myself?

Answer (score 0):

The process of installing an update doesn't have any effect on existing tiles.

Rather than delete and then repin the app you could detect when the app is started after an update (by storing the current installed version and then seeing if different when next start) and then automatically update the primary tile.